# Checking Solutions of a Second Order Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

There is a question that I got stuck on. The question is: Is there a second order linear non-homogeneous differential equation such that $x$, $\sin(x)$, $\cos(x)$ are solutions of it.

I managed to solve the same question but for a homogeneous equation. I tried to use the fact that the difference between 2 solutions of the non-homogeneous equation is a solution of the matching homogeneous equation (i.e. $\sin(x)-\cos(x)$ is a solution of the matching homogeneous equation, etc...).

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Sure, thanks :) keep in mind that the original question was in Hebrew and this is a translation:
a. Check if there exists an equation in the form y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0 where p and q are continues function in the open segment (a,b), such that the functions x, cos(x), sin(x) are solutions of the equation in that segment.
b. Are there function p(x), q(x), r(x), continues at the segment (0,2pi), such that the functions x, cos(x), sin(x) are solutions of the equation:
y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=r(x)
I managed to do the first question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is: does there exist a differential equation $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=r(x)$, with $p(x)$, $q(x)$, and $r(x)$ continuous on the interval $(0,2\pi)$, for which $y(x)=x$, $y(x)=\sin(x)$, and $y(x)=\cos(x)$ are solutions? As you correctly pointed out, in that case the difference of any two of them would be a solution to the associated homogeneous equation $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$.

So we can rephrase our task as follows: does there exist a homogeneous differential equation $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$, with $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ continuous on the interval $(0,2\pi)$, for which $y_1(x)=\sin(x)-x$ and $y_2(x)=\cos(x)-x$ are solutions?

But that is impossible. If such an equation exists, then the [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) of any two solutions would be either identically equal to zero on $(0,2\pi)$ if they are linearly dependent or never equal to zero on $(0,2\pi)$ if they are linearly independent. The Wronskian of these two functions is
$$W(y_1,y_2)=\begin{vmatrix} \sin(x)-x & \cos(x)-x \\ \cos(x)-1 & -\sin(x)-1 \end{vmatrix}=x\sin(x)+x\cos(x)+\cos(x)-\sin(x)-1.$$
It is clearly not the identically zero function (which was expected, as $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are pretty obviously not linearly dependent), but it has some roots within $(0,2\pi)$, see [the graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rxh5uxh4xs).

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!! that helped a lot :)